# Usar a camera do dispositivo

Tags: typescript, ionic3, câmera

Gostaria de usar a câmera do dispositivo mas estou encontrando dificuldade

No meu arquivo `list.ts` está ssim:

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public http: Http,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public camera: Camera) {

  }

getFoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
      }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
        // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
        let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        this.beer.img = base64Image;
       }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);

       });
  }
```

Importei também no `app.module` no provider

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
```

...

```
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Camera
  ]
```

Seguindo [esta](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera#installation) documentação, mas deu esse problema aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver?

[Aqui](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/Curso-de-Ionic/tree/master/myFirstApp) está meu projeto no git.

Comment: Ei, tenta dar uma olhada neste tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91242/abrir-camera-dentro-de-uma-div-ionic, caso não acesse a documentação relativo a sua dúvida: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

Comment: Pois é. Com a documentação não resolveu e nesse outro é em angular 1 né?

Comment: diz as tags que é em ionic.

Comment: mas o ionic usa angular e o angular daquele não é o 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Para usar a câmera normal no ionic 3 é preciso rodar rodar os seguintes comandos
Caso você já tenha no package.json um plugin coma versão 5, delete

```
1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera 
2. npm install @ionic-native/camera@4.20.0
```